# Root for IntersectionObserver using getElementById always null

Tags: javascript, html, angular, getelementbyid, intersection-observer

On an Angular project, I want to restrict the viewport of an IntersectionObserver to a specific part of a DOM.

I define the element to use as root with an id:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="page-list">
    <infinite-scroll-page (scrolled)="onInfiniteScroll()">
      ...
    </infinite-scroll-page>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the corresponding component I define the root using `getElementById`:

```
export class InfiniteScrollPageComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @Input() options: {root, threshold: number} = {root: document.getElementById('container'), threshold: 1};

  @ViewChild(AnchorDirectivePage, {read: ElementRef, static: false}) anchor: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  private observer: IntersectionObserver;

  constructor(private host: ElementRef) { }

  get element() {
    return this.host.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      const options = {
        root: document.getElementById('container'),
        ...this.options
      };

      console.log("options: ", JSON.stringify(options));
      //...
```

But the root loged is always `null`.

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your spread operator is the wrong way around, so unfortunately you're overwriting your `root` assignment immediately after it is set with the default value in the `@Input()` (which as far as I can see is not actually used as an input?).

Reversing this might be all you need to fix the issue:

```
const options = {
  root: document.getElementById('container'),
  ...this.options
};
```

should be

```
const options = {
  ...this.options,
  root: document.getElementById('container')
};
```

---

Secondly, I wonder whether it would make more sense to use `@ViewChild` and pass a reference to the container element into the `InfiniteScrollPageComponent` from the parent.

`parent.component.html`

```
<div
  #Container
  id="container">
  <div class="page-list">
    <infinite-scroll-page
      *ngIf="containerRef"
      [containerRef]="containerRef"
      (scrolled)="onInfiniteScroll()">
      ...
    </infinite-scroll-page>
  </div>
</div>
```

`parent.component.ts`

```
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('Container') containerRef: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
}
```

`infinite-page-component.component.ts`

```
export class InfiniteScrollPageComponent {
  @Input() containerRef: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const options = {
      ...this.options
      root: containerRef.nativeElement,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @nate-kumar it helps a  lot, root is not null anymore but it is set with `{}` (the log returns `options:  {"root":{},"threshold":1}"`). I have expected that root would be equal to `container`. But maybe it is the way it works